# Relative pronoun that

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

I was doing a composition and I had to use the relative pronoun in the pair of sentences.

> This is the path. 
>   He came by this path.

And its answer was **This is the path by which he came**.

But is this grammatically correct to say?

> This is the path that he came by.

Answer (score 7):

> This is the path that he came by.

Yes this makes sense, and personally sounds better than the answer you gave. ( That sounds a little bit literary for me, I wouldn't say that in real life probably).

However this sentence also has an additional meaning. It can also mean that he ( the person) could have been walking, and stumbled upon/ found a path.

Ex.

> Bob was walking in the forest and happened to come by a path.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the usage *to come **by** something* (by chance) has [massively declined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+by+it%2Ccame+across+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccame%20by%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccame%20across%20it%3B%2Cc0) relative to *come **across** it* over the past couple of centuries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers for sure, I see it in fiction books quite a bit though. I would never say it in real life sounds awkward

Comment: This second meaning of "came by" is almost always used with a qualifier stating when or what he was doing, as in your example sentence. You wouldn't normally say just "He came by this path." So it's an extremely unlikely interpretation of the sentence in the question; in that context, it almost certainly means the OP's interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

> *This is the path **by which** he came* - fine
>    *This is the path **which** he came **by*** - fine
>   *This is the path **that** he came **by*** - fine
>   *This is the path he came **by*** - fine
>    *This is the path **by that** he came* - NOT VALID

The first four all mean exactly the same, and it's a bit meaningless to say that any of them are "better" or "worse" than any others. The same principle applies to other prepositions in similar constructions...

> *This is the house **in which** he lives*, ...***which*** he lives **in**, etc., but NOT ***in that*** he lives
>    *This is the company **for which** I work*, ...***which*** I work **for**, etc.... but NOT ***for that*** I work
>   ...

Comment: I feel like "This is the path by that he came" is something that would be said in an old book from the 1500's and 1600's though. Sounds like something you would hear in a shakespear play lol

Comment: I just checked Google Books for all written instances of **by that** before 1810. There are only a couple of pages, and not one of those where I can read the context is relevant to the usage here.

Comment: oh yes it most definitely is not valid, but it sounds archaic for some reason to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

You could also say:

> This is the path he came by
>
> This is the path he came on
>
> This is the path he walked on